# Wrongly formated numbers in CSV export from Grafana graphs

Tags: export-to-csv, grafana

One of our customers has strange problem with CSV export from Grafana (3.1.1 - we still run this "ancient" version due to some other dependencies).

When they export numbers from graph showing rates as percentage, they get repeatedly strangely formatted results:

```
2018-09-11T00:00:00.000Z;44.773.054;39.500.635;37.322.795
2018-09-12T00:00:00.000Z;51.743.917;4.409.222;37.691.824
2018-09-13T00:00:00.000Z;1.421.662;4.341.522;3.631.485
```

Proper results should look like this:

```
2018-09-11T00:00:00.000Z;4.4773054;3.9500635;3.7322795
2018-09-12T00:00:00.000Z;5.1743917;4.409222;3.7691824
2018-09-13T00:00:00.000Z;1.421662;4.341522;3.631485
```

As you can see - digits are generally OK, but decimal point is gone and number is formatted as huge number with separators for thousands, millions etc.

Client uses Windows 7 Enterprise, Latest Chrome and OS is set to German lang. Our best guess is that it could be caused by some setting of LOCALs because German settings are different from UK/US settings. But we are unable to simulate it on any of our computers.

Maybe some of you already encountered something like this? I tried to google for it but did not find so far anything close enough to this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is made in the browser + numeric values are formated by [toLocaleString function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), which uses browser local setting. You need to change browser local configuration.

```js
x = 123456789
console.log('Original: ' + x)
console.log('en-EN: ' + x.toLocaleString('en-EN'))
console.log('de-DE: ' + x.toLocaleString('de-DE'))
```